# getting 'Windows Security' 'Run as different User' box, on C# Client/Server App

Tags: c#, client-server, windows-security

I have written a Client/Server App that will Start an .exe file using Process.Start on a remote computer.  I have 4 computers on my Home Network, I set the server app on PC2 and set the client app on PC1, I start listening on PC2 using Sockets and TCP.  Then when I am ready I send a command from PC1 to startup a specific program, what I get is a 'Windows Security' Box that asks me 'Run as different User' it gives me both a username and password box to type into, after I type in an administrator user and associated password the box goes away and the program starts up as intended, the problem is I don't want to type in a username and password on the remote pc everytime I want to startup a program on the remote pc.  I can send a command to shutdown the process that I just started and it works fine, but then if I try to startup the program again it requires the username and password again.  Is there a way around this in C#?  Is there some way to automagically send the username and password through C# so that I don't have that Windows Security Box popping up all the time?

As a side note when using Process.Start I use ProcessStartInfo to pass in the Verb argument "runas" which I thought would cause it to run as an admin.

Comment: FYI, apparently ProcessStartInfo has this functionality in it.  By passing the username and password into the startInfo.UserName and startInfo.Password properties you are able to bypass the security window popup.  I didn't know this.

Comment: This is the solution to your problem, right? In that case, you should add this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By passing a remote pc admin username and password into the startInfo.UserName and startInfo.Password properties you are able to bypass the security window popup.